# Git fetch a specific commit by hash

Tags: git

Git allows to fetch from any given remote and reference, for example

```
git fetch <remote-url> <reference>
```

So that those given commits are available without having to add remotes or creating branches.

This however only works for references, like branch names or tags, but not for specific hashes  and thus commits that are not referenced directly anywhere.

Is there a way to fetch a specific commit from a remote?

Comment: I suggest you change the accepted answer to reflect what is currently true https://stackoverflow.com/a/62463160/447599

Comment: @JulesG.M. the notice is appreciated!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As today I tried:

```
git fetch origin <commit-hash>
```

And it works like a charm! (git version 2.20.1)

Just be sure the `<commit-hash>` is the full length reference

Comment: a question, does it also update the branch references when we fetch with hash?

Comment: No, it just brings the commit to your local. Then you can operate on it. (e.g., you can `git checkout` it, `git cherry-pick- it`, or `git show` it)
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70381400/1797950

Comment: What if one has only the short commit hash? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70256063/retrieve-the-full-commit-hash-from-the-remote-using-a-short-hash indicates it would need to have been fetched already but that's a catch-22.

Comment: Since there shouldn't be a name clash, like with branches, is it possible to git fetch without specifying the remote? I.e. to request git to go through the available remotes and fetch from the first one that has matching commit?

Answer (score 18):

See "[Pull a specific commit from a remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/6309)":
With Git 2.5 (July 2015), you will be able to do:

```
git fetch --depth=1 <a/remote/repo.git> <full-lenght SHA1>
git cat-file commit $SHA1
```

If the SHA1 is "reachable" from one of the branch tips of the remote repo, then you can fetch it.

**Caveats**:

- you need a Git 2.5 remote repo *server* though, which will handle the `uploadpack.allowReachableSHA1InWant` config (and you need that config to be set to `true`, in order to allow a single commit fetch).
- And, as illustrated in [crgarridos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1797950/crgarridos)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62463160/6309), you need the full SHA1, and you cannot use [`git rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse), since you don't have all the commits, as noted by [Jim Hurne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106189/jim-hurne) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370157/git-fetch-a-specific-commit-by-hash/31445973#comment119563406_31445973).

Comment: Just like in the other answer here, make sure the $SHA1 is the full length reference.

Comment: @mkurz Yes, I have edited my answer to include the use of `git rev-parse`, thereby insuring I will *always* use the full-length SHA1

Comment: Unfortunately, `git rev-parse` only works reliably if you have already fetched all of the remote's commits, which of course you do not have if all you want to fetch is a single commit.

Comment: @JimHurne Good point, than you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

No. According to the manual, `git fetch` wants a refspec, the simplest form of which is a ref, and a bare SHA-1 isn't a ref. I.e., the commit has to have a name (branch, tag) on the remote for you to be able to `fetch` it.

Comment: As of 2021, this is no longer true. see @crgarridos' answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62463160/447599

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch [remote] [sha] && git checkout FETCH_HEAD` will allow you to checkout a commit that is on the remote; even if that sha is not yet merged (like in a Gerrit environment).

or... `git fetch [remote] [sha] && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD` if you wish to cherry-pick it instead.

Examples:

- `git fetch origin d8a9a9395bb0532a0498f800e38ef5e60dfb173f && git checkout FETCH_HEAD`
- `git fetch origin d8a9a9395bb0532a0498f800e38ef5e60dfb173f && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD`