# fetch git repo at specific commit without cloning

Tags: git, github, git-remote, git-fetch

I am trying to get a git repo at a specific commit hash **without cloning**! Every example wants to clone the whole repo. This makes sense but the repo I have in mind is huge and I need this to leave a small footprint as it is going with a docker image.

The commit hash is in the URL - either `wget` or `curl` could/should recursively fetch but I have a feeling github is blocking that as all I ever get is `robots.txt`

The repo and commit:

> https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/tree/1d6d21c98026b5de79ba5e75a3930ce7d1ebcd2e

my best attempt error:

```
git fetch https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/ 1d6d21c98026b5de79ba5e75a3930ce7d1ebcd2e
error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object 1d6d21c98026b5de79ba5e75a3930ce7d1ebcd2e
```

**update**

Suggestions of answers that use clone aren't answering the question. I can clone/checkout no problem. Trying to do it without having the whole repo locally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone git repository with specific revision/changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset)

Comment: Use tags, people!

Comment: You *may* have this option: https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/ (but I will warn you that using it is painful; shallow clone is much easier and more productive).

Comment: @torek definitely out-of-scope! Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 5):

You will need a Git repository, for the reason shown in the error message:

> ```
> error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object ...
> ```

An "unadvertised object" is one that does not have a name directly attached to it.  (If the object had a name, you could ask for the named thing, and the server would give you the object.  This assumes that a complaint like "I don't allow *blue* cats here" implies "I do allow some other colors of cats", which isn't necessarily true either, but it's kind of a reasonable assumption.<sup>1</sup>)  This means you must obtain the object by some indirect means, i.e., using `git fetch`.

The repository you need is, by definition, a clone—or at least a *partial* clone—of the original repository.  You can use a *shallow* clone, which is one that is incomplete.  Precisely what depth is necessary is something you cannot compute in advance: someone who has a full clone could figure it out, and once you have a deep enough clone, you can find the exact number.  But if your clone is too shallow, all you know is that your clone is too shallow.

See also [Git fetch a specific commit by hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370157/git-fetch-a-specific-commit-by-hash) and [git shallow clone (clone --depth) misses remote branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23708231/1256452).  Note that you may or may not want `--single-branch`.  Clone with some depth and see if it's enough, and if not, raise the depth with `git fetch --depth <bigger-number>` until it is enough.

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, this logic appears to be the true origin for the phrase "the exception that proves the rule": it comes from the Latin phrase *Exceptio probat regulam in casibus non exceptis*.  See https://pocketbookuk.com/tag/cicero/ and [this answer on english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/14213/180540) for more on this.

Comment: So you can fetch before doing clone?