# Why doesn't git ls-remote list all the remote refs?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-fetch, git-ls-remote

I have a remote repo (`origin`) whose `refs` directory contains, in addition to the usual `heads`, `tags`, and `remotes` subdirectories, also  `keep-around` and `merge-requests`.  These are special sets of refs that are managed by [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) for its internal housekeeping.

When I use `git ls-remote` to interrogate this repo, the command lists the `merge-requests` refs but not the `keep-around` requests:

```
$ git ls-remote
5ef8f113ba35360de0dfc015601bb832bacb5505        HEAD
... lots of refs/heads/...
... lots of refs/merge-requests/...
... lots of refs/tags...
```

Similarly, I can fetch `merge-requests` refs, for example with

```
$ git fetch origin refs/merge-requests/999/head
From git.company.com:Company/company
 * branch                    refs/merge-requests/999/head -> FETCH_HEAD
```

but when I ask for a `keep-around` ref, the remote repo claims it doesn't exist, even though I know it does:

```
$ git fetch origin  refs/keep-around/291ad6a6bebf067377700d430ac130d758ed52e9
fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/keep-around/291ad6a6bebf067377700d430ac130d758ed52e9
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I don't see anything in the remote repo's `config` that seems to relate to this.  What's causing the different behavior?

---

Addendum: Meredith Howard suggests that this may be a feature of Gitlab; there is a special Gitlab config that tells it specifically to hide the refs in `refs/keep-around`. See [this support request from someone with a similar question](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/28685).

---

Addendum: It has been suggested that this is a duplicate of [Git fetch a specific commit by hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370157/git-fetch-a-specific-commit-by-hash) .  I am not trying to fetch a specific commit by hash.  I want to know why the remote repo is omitting certain refs from its listing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git fetch a specific commit by hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370157/git-fetch-a-specific-commit-by-hash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every Git web-hosting site can, through whatever configuration mechanisms that site uses (most likely a `--system` config file), hide whatever references it likes.  Git itself has a general-purpose mechanism for this: `transfer.hideRefs`.  See [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corewhitespace) for details.  If you run your own servers, you can set them up this way.