# Why are commits that show up in "Pushes" not showing in "History"?

Tags: git, tfs

Environment: On-prem TFS, Git repository

For the past month, we have one specific user that has commits "disappear" from history, along with the actual changes.  When I go to the Code view and select the Pushes tab, I see every commit (along with the SHA hash) from this user.  If I look at the details of the commit from this view, I can see that it was "Pushed by [user]" and "refs/heads/[branch] udpated from ... to ..." along with diffs.  This all seems normal and correct.

When I go to the Commits tab of the same repository and look at the commits for [branch], none of the commits are present from this user starting from a specific date.  The user's remote branch tracking seems correct and the commits are definitely getting sent, otherwise they wouldn't show up in the Pushes view.  I also cannot find any of these commits using Git Bash with any of the following commands:

```
$ git branch --contains [short hash]
error: malformed object name [short hash]

$ git branch --contains [full hash]
error: no such commit [full hash]

$ git log -p [short hash]
fatal: ambiguous argument '[short hash]': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

$ git log -p [full hash]
fatal: bad object [full hash]

$ git show [short hash]
fatal: ambiguous argument '[short hash]': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

$ git show [full hash]
fatal: bad object [full hash]
```

Anyone have any ideas or insight as to what might be going on?  I will add any additional details that I can - I just don't know what's relevant at this point.

Comment: gc getting in the middle?

Comment: ```gc getting in the middle?``` for only one user?

Comment: Different users (different local repos) might have different gc configurations. Perhaps that user has gc configured too aggressively?

Comment: ```...configured too aggressively?``` Hmmm, alright.  It's definitely something I haven't checked yet, so it can't hurt.  Would local gc affect commits that are pushed to the remote?

Comment: Nope... and i would guess the _remote_ itself could have a gc set up too? Say, I mean, the repo where you should see the gc configuration is the one where you were running those commands on.

Comment: I was running it on my own local repo.  I don't think I can run it against TFS's remote.  It's just weird that TFS can see these commits as "Pushes", but not as "Commits" and Git Bash can't find them at all.

Comment: Well.... i don't know how TFS works _but_ if it's stuff from another developer, then those revisions were never on your local _unless_ TFS presents them to you somehow (branches?)... at least from git's POV.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233936/discussion-between-codehxr-and-eftshift0).

Comment: Hmm... could someone have done an interactive rebase to retroactively remove the commits?  If so, how would I detect that?

Comment: You? From your local repo? You can't... unless you had a branch that pointed in one direction and then the branch remotely points to a different history, then you would know for sure that history was rewritten (git would tell you that there was a forced-push when fetching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If an interactive rebase was, in fact, done... I'd have no way to tell from my local Git repository, or even the remote repository.
> It's still possible, though, that this could've happened and wiped out a month's worth of one developer's commits? (on purpose or not is irrelevant)

No, it should not have wiped out anything. Even if the SHA1 are changed by a rebased, the commits should (unless squashed or dropped by the rebase) be there.

From what I can see in the [TFS push API](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-be/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1), the Pushes view display push *events*.
But if, for example, a branch (where those commits were pushed) was *deleted* (making those commits potentially un-referenced), then you would no longer see them in the visible history of that repository, nor would you be able to fetch them.

Actually, you can try and [fetch the last developer's commit SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62463160/6309) directly, to see if said commit is still stored (in reflog) by the TFS remote Git repository.
If that works, then you can create a local branch from said fetched commit, and push back that branch: that would make the developer's invisible history visible again.

Comment: I'm not in this repository on a day-to-day basis, so is there a way I can tell if a particular branch was, in fact, deleted/recreated?  Would it have a different tree ID or something?

Comment: @CodeHxr Not sure, unless TFS proposes an audit activity log somewhere.

Comment: @CodeHxr A branch recreated on the same commit would make those commits visible again, no "branch-id" involved there. My answer is about a branch deleted, branch which was the last object referencing those user's commits: the deletion would make them invisible (present only in the remote TFS reflog, and only for 90 days max)

Comment: I was able to fetch the missing commit by using your 2nd link: ```git fetch origin [full hash]```.  It returned: ```* branch            [random hash] -> FETCH_HEAD``` which indicates to me that the branch it was committed to is messed up or deleted.  Is that how you interpret the response?  (btw: you get the bounty, so thank you!)

Comment: @CodeHxr Yes, the branch is gone, but since you have fetch its HEAD commit, you can now create a local branch based on it, and push back said local branch, thereby restoring it for all to use.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thank you again for the information! =)