# Retrieve the full commit hash from the remote using a short hash

Tags: git

Say, i have and only know a short commit hash `c4cde4c4` which is in the remote repo. It **hasn't been fetched** into my **local** yet. Is there a way to retrieve the full commit hash for `c4cde4c4` by using **git commands** either on the client side or the remote git server side? (*Don't tell me to fetch it. It's not my question*)

Note, `git rev-parse c4cde4c4` won't work on the client side in this case, unless `c4cde4c4` has been fetched into local. It just returns the following:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'c4cde4c4': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
> Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
> 'git  [...] -- [...]'
>
> c4cde4c4

Comment: The git server in question may provide a propriatary API to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible by design.

If you do not want to fetch, you have to log in to the remote server (your question does imply that you can issue git commands on the remote server side) and run `git rev-parse c4cde4c4` there.

Comment: The OP didn't say they didn't want to fetch. The issue is that `git fetch` requires the full commit hash and doesn't work with the short commit hash so there's a catch-22.